# Reader not returning rows on check of Table Existance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know for sure this table exists yet the reader has no rows.  I expect the name of the table to come back if it exists

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'" + tableName + "') AND type in (N'U')", SqlConnection))
{
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    {
        using (reader)
        {
            if (!reader.HasRows) return false;

            while (reader.Read())
                tableNameFound = reader.GetString(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this query straight up in Management Studio and I do get back "Cars":

```
SELECT name FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Cars') AND type in (N'U')
```

so maybe I shouldn't be using reader here?  I don't know.

Comment: You could use `cmd.ExecuteScalar`, however, both should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine.

Check:

- If you run this on the correct database / schema. This query will fail when running it in `master` for example when your table is in another database / schema;
- If the parameter you enter doesn't contain spaces, etc.